# what is the Use of middlegen and XDoclet and the difference between them?

Tags: ejb

i know but i have no more idea about it and i don't know perfectly so and they both are use for ejb framework.

Answer (score 0):

Both xdoclet and middlegen were tools for generating code for the EJB 1.x and EJB 2.x frameworks, which were a real pig to use on their own.  However, EJB 2.x is now obsolete, and so are those tools. Comparing and contrasting them is, as a result, pretty pointless.